# How to Config Social Networks Login inside AppDelegate OpenURLOptionsKey

Tags: swift, appdelegate, uiapplication, openurl

How to configure social login inside openurl.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
      return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
    // [END openurl]
    // [START openurl_new]
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {

        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            options: options
        )

      return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }
```

How this three social login **Facebook/GooglePlus/LinkedIn** need to handle inside `open url` below version `UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
func application(_ application:UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]) -> Bool {
            print("called")
            let fbShared = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                                  annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
            let twitterShared = TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: options)
            return fbShared || twitterShared
        }
```